# AWS Autoscaling group policy for cross region auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have a service running entirely in US-EAST-1. Recently as we scaled up we used almost all of the available GPU instances in that region, so the aws team recommended we explore using instances from another region. So I have created an Auto scaling group in us-west-1 which would read and write to sqs and databases in us east 1.
I want to create an auto scaling policy for expanding which would first increase the instances in us east 1 when traffic increases and then if we reach a threshold of instances, we start scaling out in us west 1. What would be an ideal policy and which metrics should I be using?
I was thinking of using these:

1. number of visible messages in sqs
2. gpu and cpu usage of instances
   based on these 2 increase instances in us east , and once we reach 60-70 instances in east 1, start scaling out in us west 1.
   does this make sense?

I was thinking of using these:

1. number of visible messages in sqs
2. gpu and cpu usage of instances
   based on these 2 increase instances in us east , and once we reach 60-70 instances in east 1, start scaling out in us west 1.
   does this make sense?